# Odoo10 Chinese(HK) language pack

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have Odoo10 on my Ubuntu 14.04 system. And I want that in my Odoo all content visible in English as well as Chinese(HK). For this I use Odoo basic feature **Translations --> Load a Translation**, add load Chinese(HK) Language. And also select user preference language to Chinese(HK). But I don't get the desired result, which is I want. So, Is it possible to have the interface display everything in two languages simultaneously? That would be very useful in multi language companies for example (English/Chinese(HK)).

So anyone can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the desire result, which you want?

Comment: I want that, complete content available in english as well as chinese(HK). For example "cleaning are" is Cleaning Area( 清潔間).

Comment: It isn't supported in Odoo.

Comment: Hello, Is there is any solution to convert odoo default module in chinese(HK). Now, i converted custom module by exporting and importing method easily. But, this not work for default module.